# html5media extracted code not working

Tags: html, javascript, html5-audio

I'm using the java script library `html5media.min.js` to play `mp3` file in `Firefox`.
my problem is that when I add the script link to my page as:

```
<script src = "http://api.html5media.info/1.1.5/html5media.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It is working fine.
But if I get the code and save it in a local file, it is not working!!
i.e.

```
<script src="Scripts/html5media.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: are you sure about the cap in Scripts, also where is located the file which call the js

Comment: it is located in the root where the folder script is.
and i tested other scripts in the same location and is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this code into your page after the the script tag

```
html5media.flowplayerSwf = "/path/to/your/flowplayer.swf";
html5media.flowplayerAudioSwf = "/path/to/your/flowplayer.audio.swf";
html5media.flowplayerControlsSwf = "/path/to/your/flowplayer.controls.swf";
```

You can see [this](http://code.google.com/p/html5media/wiki/HostingYourOwn)